# Org-mode File Types

Tags: org-mode

I haven't been able to find in the documentation the role of a few file types created by org-mode to support the main org file.

`file.org` is the main file

`file.org_archive` is clearly where archived tasks are stored

what are these: `file.org_archive~` , `file.org~`, `.#file.org`, `#file.org#`

Opened in a text editor, they look the same as `file.org`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are all backup or lock files of one sort of another that emacs itself creates (i.e. they have nothing to do with org-mode: emacs does this for all files). See [Backup](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Backup.html#Backup) in the Emacs docs: this explains the files with `~` appended.

The `.#file.org` file is a lock file that is created when you modify `file.org` but have not saved it yet. It's supposed to protect the file from simultaneous editing by multiple users. See [Protection against Simultaneous Editing](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Interlocking.html#Interlocking).

The file `#file.org#` is a saved copy of the corresponding file `file.org` that emacs currently is visiting. As long as you keep the `file.org` file open, the backup file will be periodically saved with the current contents of the buffer, so that if emacs crashes[1] you will have lost only a little bit of what you had done. When you save the file and kill the buffer visiting it, this backup file will go away. See [Auto-Save Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Auto-Save-Files.html#Auto-Save-Files).

The docs describe a bunch of options that you can set to change the default behavior.

[1] Emacs never crashes of course.[2]

[2] Just kidding :-)